# logic question about factorials

Tags: logic

I have a problem and can't solve it alone. My teacher gives me one logic task today, and i'm sure you can help me.

How can I count the number of zeroes at the end of **factorial(41)**. (**on paper**)
I understand that it has nothing to do with programing, but I'm sure programers can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Syom, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I suppose the voter thought: no homework, bad English, OP immediately asked instead of providing information about tries he did, or a combination of these points

Comment: @jball i'm not good in english, please rewrite your question

Comment: @syom: its a programming question, but improve the post by mentioning what you did.

Comment: @Syom, what attempts have you made on your own?

Comment: @Veger i'm  improoving my english, i think about this task much, i know, that i must count the number of "2" and "5" - s in the number, but i can't get the final result:(

Comment: Don't worry about your English if people say things, it's pretty good.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174505

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
floor(n/5) + floor(n/25) + floor(n/125)+.......+floor(n/5^n)
```

in your case n = 41

---

See comments below

Comment: round here shows that only integer part of each expression should be considered (yes, floor)

Comment: @Sorantis: `round(9/5) = 2` and `floor(9/5) = 1`

Comment: n=41, not 9 ... (9/5) was just an example for demonstrating floor vs. round

Answer (score 7):

If you know the trick, you don't even need paper.  The number of zeros at the end is how many times it's divisible by 10 . . . in terms of the prime factorization, this is the minimum of the number of times it's divisible by 5 and the number of times it's divisible by 2 (since we need one factor of *both* 2 and 5 to make a factor of 10).  But with factorial we're including every factor less than or equal to 41, so we'll get a lot more factors of 2 than factors of 5.  So we only need to worry about how many factors of 5 there are.

So count the numbers that are less than or equal to 41 and divisible by 5:
5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40

There's 8 of them, but don't forget that 25 gives us an extra factor of 5, since it's divisible by 5 twice.  So 9 factors of 5 (and thus 9 factors of 10) in all.

Comment: Good explanation. I just wrote the result of it in one formula. I thought it was pretty obvious. My bad

Comment: @Syom, it mean that you didn't really understand the question you were asked. And coming back to your question it means that there's 49 digits more, written in scientific format.

Comment: @Syom: That's scientific notation . . . it means 3.345... times 10 to the 49th power.  But often with scientific notation some of the digits are truncated.  In this case the exact answer is 33452526613163807108170062053440751665152000000000, or in other words 3.3452526613163807108170062053440751665152 x 10^49  [Source: WolframAlpha -- just type in 41! (the ! means factorial)]

Comment: However, don't go turning that answer in . . . the point of the problem is surely to understand the factorization so you don't *have* to actually compute 41!

Comment: @Syom: I'm a little hesitant to post my contact info on a public forum, and unfortunately StackOverflow doesn't currently support private messaging.  I'll keep replying to comments here if you want to discuss further . . . or if you have a followup question that's pretty far from this one perhaps it deserves its own topic.