# c++ Number of zeros in a factorial number

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Counting trailing zeros of numbers resulted from factorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174505/counting-trailing-zeros-of-numbers-resulted-from-factorial)

It is given an integer "p". I have to find a number "n" for which "n factorial" has "p" numbers of zero at the end. Here is the solution i thought, but i am not sure if it is a solution for this problem. Do i have to make a function to calculate the factorial and another function to get the zeros?

```
int p;
int count5=0;
int i;
int copy_i;

printf("Enter p: ");
scanf("%d",&p);

for(i=1; ;i++)
{
    copy_i=i;

    while(copy_i/5)
    {
        if(copy_i%5==0)
        {
            count5++;
            copy_i=copy_i/5;
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    if(count5==p)
    {
        printf("The minimum number n is: %d.",i);
        break;
    }
    else if(count5>p) 
    {
        printf("No match for n! with %d zero.",p);
        break;
    }

}
```

Comment: Why are you not sure if it is correct? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: I made the tests and are all ok. This is a problem for my homework and my teacher said that is not a solution for my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a Project Euler problem, so I won't give an explicit solution. Here's two hints though:

- You do not have to actually calculate the factorial to find out how many zeroes it has at the end.
- If a number is divisible by 2^N and by 5^N, the number has at least N zeroes at the end.