# C++: Counting zeros at the end optimization

Tags: c++, algorithm, optimization

I am trying to solve standard problem of calculating 0s at the end of factorial of any natural number. My code works fine but online judge gives "Time Limit Exceeded" error. Decided to ask here about how I can optimize my code.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int count (int n)
{
    int result = 0;
    for (unsigned int i = 5; i <= n; i += 5)
    {
        int temp = i;
        while (!(temp % 5))
        {
            ++result;
            temp /= 5;
        }
    }
    return result;
}



int main()
{
    int N;
    cin >> N;
    cin.get();
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        int n;
        cin >> n;
        cin.get();
        cout << count (n) << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Might you need something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889999/c-number-of-zeros-in-a-factorial-number#  ?

Comment: you are assigning unsigned int to int. Change all ints to uints

Comment: does it really take more time than assigning int to int or unsigned int to unsigned int, for example?

Comment: @KudayarPirimbaev: `int` to `unsigned int` is "free", in that the bitwise representation is copied as is. What is surprising is that the bitwise representation has a different meaning depending when you fall into values that are representable by only one of the two (typically, negative values).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
int count (int n)
{
    int result = 0;
    for (unsigned int i = 5; i <= n; i *= 5)
        result += n / i;
    return result;
}
```

In `1*2*..*N`, there are `N/5` factors, which are divisable by `5`. `N/25` of those are also divisable by `25`, ...

Answer (score 1):

You haven't to check every number divisible by 5. Instead you can count 5's with simple series:

```
count =  n div 5 + n div 25 + n div 125...
```