# What is the fastest way to find the exact value of the factorial of a large number in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, math

I'm aiming at particularly large values of the number whose factorial is to be found for example- 12345678!. Even     `math.factorial(12345678)`     in python takes a lot of time to compute the factorial of such a number.

I tried Stirling's Appoximation to compute the same but it does not give the exact value. Is there any other method to compute the same?

EDIT 1: This is the preview of the code I tried to compute the trailing zeros in factorial of the number

```
import math

def main():
    total_cases = int(eval(raw_input()))

    for case in xrange(total_cases):
        number = int(eval(raw_input()))

        if number >= 1e9:
            break

        factorial_n = math.factorial(number)

        count = 0

        for i in xrange(1, number):
            temp = 10**i

            if factorial_n % temp == 0 :
                count += 1
            else:
                print count
                break

main()
```

EDIT 2: I just found that the bottleneck is the dividing step.

Comment: Computing `math.factorial(12345)` on my (not particularly fast) machine takes about 6 milliseconds.  What do you mean by "a lot of time"?

Comment: I should note that Python 3 (at least Python 3.2 and later) use a better algorithm than Python 2.x.  But I still get a time of less than 0.1 seconds on Python 2.  What Python version are you using?

Comment: Your algorithm is poor. This is not a problem of `factorial`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Counting trailing zeros of numbers resulted from factorial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174505/counting-trailing-zeros-of-numbers-resulted-from-factorial)

Comment: @simonzack Any recommendations on improving algorithm?

Comment: @gsmanu007: Don't compute the factorial and *then* count zeros: find a way to count the zeros without computing the entire factorial.  Hint: think about prime factorizations, or see the question that simonzack linked to.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Thanks a lot for the helpful comments. Eventually I learnt a new method!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scipy` has a fast C implementation for both an approximation and exact values.

```
scipy.misc.factorial(12345, exact=True)
```

Tried this myself, takes under a second.

But upon trying `math.factorial(12345)` it also takes under a second. Have you tried this yourself?

Comment: Interestingly, SciPy's version is about a factor of 7 slower than the math module version, on my machine (under Python 3.4).

Comment: I don't use SciPy (AFAIK :) ), but [mpmath](https://mpmath.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/build/functions/gamma.html) can do _ginormous_ factorials, both exact & approximate.

Answer (score 0):

```
    def factorial(n):
        result = 1
        for i in range (1, (n +1)):
            result = i * result
        return result
    
    print (factorial (100))
```

This code computes the factorial of a number by using range function and for loop.