# Number trailing zeros in factorial in java

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
class factorial {

    void fact(int a) {
        int i;
        int ar[] = new int[10000];
        int fact = 1, count = 0;
        for (i = 1; i <= a; i++) {

            fact = fact * i;
        }
        String str1 = Integer.toString(fact);
        int len = str1.length();
        i = 0;
        do {
            ar[i] = fact % 10;
            fact /= 10;
            i++;
        } while (fact != 0);
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (ar[i] == 0) {
                count = count + 1;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(count);
    }
    public static void main(String...ab) {
        int a;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        a = input.nextInt();
        factorial ob = new factorial();
        ob.fact(a);
    }
}
```

This code is work up to `a = 10` but after enter number larger then `a = 16` it gives wrong answer.
Please help.
    As I am not able to post this question if I dont add more info for this question but I assume that the info I provide above is enough to under stand what I want.

Comment: Sufficiently large factorials will overflow `int`, then it will overflow `long`.  You could use `BigInteger`, but you don't need to.  Keep track of how many factors of 2 and 5 are in the product.  That will tell the number of trailing zeros.

Comment: Ohk Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Since you need the min(#2's, #5's), and there are far more factors of two in the product, you really only need to keep track of the number of factors of 5.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Counting trailing zeros of numbers resulted from factorial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174505/counting-trailing-zeros-of-numbers-resulted-from-factorial)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Note, this is not the mathematical solution as others suggested, this is just a refactoring of what he had initially...

Here I just used BigInteger in place of Int, and simplified your code abit. Your solution is still not optimal. I thought I would just show you what a refactored version of what you posted may look like. Also there was a bug in your initial function. It returned the number of zeros in the whole number instead of just the number of trailing zeros.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Scanner;

class factorial {

    public static void main(String... ab) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a = input.nextInt();
        fact(a);
    }

    private static void fact(int a) {
        BigInteger fact = BigInteger.ONE;
        int i, count = 0;
        for (i = 1; i <= a; i++) {
            fact = fact.multiply(new BigInteger(Integer.toString(i)));
        }
        String str1 = fact.toString();
        for(int j = str1.length() - 1; j > -1; j--) {
            if(Character.digit(str1.charAt(j), 10) != 0) {
                System.out.println(count);
                break;
            } else {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Like many of these mathematical puzzles, you are expected to simplify the problem to make it practical.  You need to find how many powers of ten in a factorial, not calculate a factorial and then find the number of trailing zeros.

The simplest solution is to count the number of powers of five.  The reason you only need to count powers of five is that there is plenty of even numbers in between then to make a 10.  For example, 5! has one 0, 10! has 2, 15! has three, 20! has four, and 25! has not five but six as 25 = 5 * 5.

In short you only need calculate the number of powers of five between 1 and N.

```
// floor(N/5) + floor(N/25) + floor(N/125) + floor(N/625) ...
public static long powersOfTenForFactorial(long n) {
    long sum = 0;
    while (n >= 5) {
       n /= 5;
       sum += n;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Note: This will calculate the trailing zeros of Long.MAX_VALUE! in a faction of a second, whereas trying this with BigInteger wouldn't fit, no matter how much memory you had.

Answer (score 0):

Without using factorial

```
public class TrailingZero {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println(trailingZeroes(9247));

}

public static int trailingZeroes(int a) {
    int countTwo = 0;
    int countFive = 0;

    for (int i = a; i > 1; i--) {
        int local = i;
        while (local > 1) {
            if (local % 2 != 0) {
                break;
            }

            local = local / 2;
            countTwo++;

        }

        while (local > 1) {
            if (local % 5 != 0) {
                break;
            } else {
                local = local / 5;
                countFive++;
            }

        }


    }


    return Math.min(countTwo, countFive);
}}
```